# Magento 2 cannot Disable 3rd party plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin, amasty

Im trying to disable Amasty\Gdpr\Block\AccountLinkPlugin from my vendor folder.

Amasty frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation">
    <plugin name="amasty-gdpr-account-navigation" type="Amasty\Gdpr\Block\AccountLinkPlugin"/>
</type>
```

so i tried creating a module to disable it.

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_AmastyGdpr" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Amasty_Gdpr" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

etc/di.xml (i also tried putting it in etc/frontend/di.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation">
        <plugin name="amasty-gdpr-account-navigation" disabled="true"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

already tried different approaches to make this work. like including the 'type' on the di.xml, but it didnt work. also saw a some question and solution here. but for some reasons its not working for me. im using 2.4.0.

im sure that im trying to remove the correct plugin cause when i tried to do

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation">
    <plugin name="amasty-gdpr-account-navigation" type="Amasty\Gdpr\Block\AccountLinkPlugin" disabled="true"/>
</type>
```

directly on the amasty module, it did work.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

There are three different ways to disable a module.

1. This file - `app/etc/config.php`  then find your module name, then make it to 0 from 1 , it will disable the module.
2. To disable a module from command line.
   For example, to disable the Weee module, enter:

```
$ bin/magento module:disable Magento_Weee
```

3. It may be helpful - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html

Comment: Hi @Vibhore Jain, i dont want to disable the whole Amasty_Gdpr module. i just want to disable one of its plugins.

Comment: Try comment the <plugin> tag in all related files.

Comment: Your above code seems ok, run setup upgrade and compile it again, deploy -f , chmod 777 var pub, then clean: cache..

Comment: @VibhoreJain You clearly don't understand his question